# Is this a puzzle? Cup cakes

Tags: mathematics, pattern, visual, puzzle-identification

[image: a cupcake with number icing]
This picture was in a pippi long-stocking book ( the lauren child version).

[image: front cover]
[image: left side]
[image: right side]
This picture looked to me like it should be a sequence.

Does it?

Comment: Might be easier to tell if you transcribed the text above it.

Comment: Looks like a "find the duplicates" (there are two) type of kids' puzzle.

Comment: @RupertMorrish the text above is just the story, about pippi Going for coffee, with cakes on the table.

Comment: @WendyG It is a bit strange that each number has a dot next to it. Could the numbers be page numbers or perhaps positions of items in a list?

Comment: A second picture of the whole page might be helpful

Comment: Do you know who the illustrator was and have a link to the exact book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an artistic choice.

The surrounding cupcakes also have numbers in specific ranges. Interestingly enough, there is no crossover with the numbers apart from "30." appearing in the orange cupcake as well (at the edge of the page). Id say its safe to assume that each cupcake contains a unique range of numbers and doubles of the numbers on the bounds of the range. There appears to be no correlation with the position of a number in the cupcake and its value however I cannot say that there is no link between the properties of numbers and the cupcakes that they're in.

From this information I will say that this illustration is supposed to display the calculating nature of Pippi. She sees sugar as just a number and wants to raise it as high as possible in a short amount of time. The duplicate numbers shows her efforts in stringing the cakes together. The randomness of the numbers shows her erratic nature in stuffing her face.

Answer (score 1):

Were it not for the two "1."s and that the outcome seems to just be a scribble, I'd say it was a join the dots puzzle.

Comment: How odd, there are also two "30."s and the numbers are all from 1-30 with no omissions